# PWA call POST request from server.js to API in Laravel - 419 unknow status

Tags: laravel, post, progressive-web-apps, fetch-api

I have PWA application. In Server.js I have method that send POST request to API written in PHP Laravel.
This is the method in server.js:

```
    fetch('http://localhost:8082/testsapp/public/addusertester', {                                
             method: 'POST',
           /*  headers: {
               'auth': '1234'                            
             },*/
              body: JSON.stringify({                     
             samedata: 'dean',
             samedata2: 'dean123',
           })
         })
.then(function (data) {                         
        console.log('addUserTester Request success: ', data);

     })
```

In PHP method looks like that:

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Exception;
    use DB as Database;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
    //use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;

    class UserController extends Controller
    {
        public function addUserTesterPost(Request $request)
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => 'Adam', 
            'surname' => 'KKKK',
            'company' => 'Google',
            'password' => 'asdf',
            'usertype' => 'tester',
            'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())
        ]);

        return "email added";
    }
    ...
```

and in web.php routing is set:

```
Route::post('/addusertester', 'UserController@addUserTesterPost');
```

And when I call method in PWA in Server.js I get response:

```
addUserTester Request success:  Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _transformState: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'http://localhost:8082/testsapp/public/addusertester',
    status: 419,
    statusText: 'unknown status',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

Result of the method is success but method in PHP isn't called, because any row isn't added to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel I had to set:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    protected $except = [
        '*'
    ];
}
```

Now is ok